# Reference for amazing generalized version of Morera's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I recently came to know about following amazing  generalized version of  Morera's Theorem:

**Theorem**:Let $f$ be a continuous function on the complex plane and suppose that there exist numbers $ r_1,r_2 >0$  such that $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz =0$$ for every circle  $\gamma$ with radius $r_1$ or $r_2$ (and arbitrary center).Then $f$ is an $entire$ function unless $r_1/r_2$  is a quotient of zeros of the Bessel function $J_1(z)$.
Can Someone please give a reference for this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "Offbeat Integral Geoemtry" by Lawrence Zalcman[1]. This lovely theorem is in section 11, "Extensions". Two references are given.

[1] http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Zalcman161-175.pdf

Comment: ahh.Thank you ! Regards,